# QML: connect slot to several controls

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I would like to get notification in main Qt app in case any control in QML (loaded via `QQuickWidget`) changes its value. There are `CheckBox`'es, `ComboBox`'es, `SpinBox`'es and `TextEditor`'s.
My current approach is to declare a slot for every control (`onCheckedChanged`, `onCurrentIndexChanged`, `onValueChanged` and `onTextChanged` respectively) and call `mainApp.notifyMe()` from them, there `mainApp` is a link to parent Qt Widget propagated to QML with help of

```
QQmlEngine* engine = new QQmlEngine(this);
if (QQmlContext* cntx = engine->rootContext()) {
            cntx->setContextProperty("mainApp", this);
}
```

and `notifyMe()` is a slot in it on C++ side.

But this requires dozens of functions with the same code bcs I have dozens of controls. It would be ideal to have one or 4 functions with notifyMe() in QML which could be connected to all controls value changes.

Is there a way in QML to create such slot and connect it to multiple objects property changes?

Comment: There will be no escape for the code to be specific on signal type i.e how about _a function_  that loops all controls having `onCurrentIndexChanged`  and connects to the slot

Answer (score 0):

I've end up with following in my root item:

```
MySettingsForm {

    signal notify()

    onNotify: {
        mainApp.notifyMe();
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var cbs = [Combobox1, Combobox2, Combobox3];
        for (var i in cbs) {
            cbs[i].checkedChanged.connect(notify);
        }
        var sbs = [SpinBox1, SpinBox2, SpinBox3];
        for (i in sbs) {
            sbs[i].valueChanged.connect(notify);
        }
        var tes = [TextField1, TextFiel2, TextField3];
        for (i in tes) {
            tes[i].textChanged.connect(notify);
        }
        var cxs = [ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3];
        for (i in cxs) {
            cxs[i].currentIndexChanged.connect(notify);
        }
    }
...
}
```

The trick is in creation of custom signal `notify` and slot attached to it.